# how to embed videos on the mobile app

Tags: iphone, video, mobile

how to embed videos on the mobile app so that it works for iphone and droids? here is what i am using and it seems like it does not work for driod phones.... any help?

```
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" 
codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
<param name="src" value="http://hostname/images/Large.jpg" />
<param name="href" value="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.mp4" />
<param name="target" value="myself" />
<param name="controller" value="false" />
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="scale" value="aspect" />
<embed type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
src="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.jpg" href="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.mp4" target="myself" 
controller="false" autoplay="false" scale="aspect" />
</object>
</noscript>
</div>

<div class="video-desc"><a href="/video.aspx?videoCollectionNumber=1&language=" title="Clean Hands" target="_self"><span class="title">Clean Hands</span><span class="released">Sat, May 02, 2009</span><span class="description">Clean hands....</span></a></div></li></ul><ul class="menu"><li><h1 class="phone">Videos</h1><ul class="video-list"><li><div class="video">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using HTML5's `<video>` tag to embed video for iPhone/Droid.

Comment: can you please explain why should i use html 5?

Comment: Because it's widely supported on modern smartphones, particularly iOS/Android.

Comment: If you only need to support Android and iOS, you can just do `<video src="http://hostname/mobile/videos/green.mp4" poster="http://hostname/images/Large.jpg" width="123" height="456"></video>`. If you need support for Firefox, Chrome, etc., read http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html.

Comment: targeting both andriod and iphone

Comment: it did not work, on my andriod phone i dont get any video or anything the page is blank, am i missing anything?